# iOS: Connect to MongoDB using parse

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-server

I do not find any simple iOS related article/ document that may guide to setup parse server, mongoDB setup and able to make connection with the database.

I am new to both Parse and MongoDB. On my mac machine (MAC OS X Sierra), I created the parse server using the steps mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example)

I have downloaded the binary for MongoDB from the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

and performed a manual install as per the steps for manual installation. The parse server setup provides applicationID, master key for the parse server. I have also downloaded MongoDB Compass application to be able to connect to the locally created Mongodb database.

Can anyone point me on how to use MongoDB from parse server ?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Its sad to see this question down voted but my below findings may help anyone struggling to communicate with parse server (local installation) using an iOS application

**To install parse server (locally)**
From termainl run below command
sudo npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
I used sudo command on MAC OS X Sierra since without it the installation is getting failed.

**To start MongoDB**
Run below command
mongodb-runner start

**To run parse server(locally)**
Run below command
parse-server --appId  --masterKey  --databaseURI

**To install parse dashboard (For managing the app)**
Run below command
sudo npm install -g parse-dashboard

**To run parse dashboard**
Run below command
parse-dashboard --appId  --masterKey  --serverURL "http://localhost:1337/parse"

Once all above steps accomplished successfully. One can start communicating with a locally installed parse server through the parse iOS SDK